# FOSRestBundle - Use ParamConverter to set current user

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, fosrestbundle

Usually, On public APIs with multiple customers - all Entities should belong to a specific Entity (I.e Company, User etc.) - The owner of that Entity.

---

### Example

Entity Resource:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="resource", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"customer_id", "name"})
 * })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"customer", "name"}, groups={"save"})
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Resource
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose()
     * @JMS\Groups({"save_response"})
     * @JMS\Type(name="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Customer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @JMS\Type("AppBundle\Entity\Customer")
     */
    private $customer;

...
}
```

Entity Customer:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection<Resource>
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Resource", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Entity\Resource>"))
     */
    private $resources;
..
}
```

Controller:

```
class VariableController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Post(path="", name="resource_add")
     * @ParamConverter("resource", converter="fos_rest.request_body", options={"validator"={"groups"="save"}, "deserializationContext"={"groups"={"save"}}})
     * @param Resource $resource
     * @param ConstraintViolationList $validationErrors
     * @return View
     */
    public function addAction(Resource $resource ConstraintViolationList $validationErrors)
    {
        if (count($validationErrors)) { //Doesn't check for EntityUnique constraint - because its empty on request
            return $this->view($validationErrors, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $resource->setCustomer($this->getUser()->getCustomer()); //This should be done automatically

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($resource);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->view($resource, 200);
    }
}
```

### Issue

`Resource`'s `@UniqueEntity(fields={"customer", "name"}, groups={"save"})` is not used, simply because Customer relation is empty.

---

### Question

Is there a way to set the logged-in user (or one of his relations) on a `Resource` using @ParamConverter?

Please advise,
Thanks!

Comment: Why you use @UniqueEntity in Resource entity and for fields user that is a whole entity User? you must use scalar field to make it unique not whole entity.

Comment: You probably miss understood the question. In case and you have a `Category` Entity, it make sense to make it unique by name, right? So how will you address this requirement when you have multiple customers on the same system? You need to have a unique constraint on 2 fields (category.name, category.company). It may sound simple if you work with FormType, but it doesn't work like that if you want to use `@ParamConverer` and Entity annotation out of the box. Checkout my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Event Subscriber, listen to `serializer.post_deserialize`.

#### service.yml:

```
company.aware.subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Request\API\CompanyAwareSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

#### CompanyAwareSubscriber:

```
namespace AppBundle\Request\API;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;


/**
 *
 */
class CompanyAwareSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorage
     */
    protected $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @param $tokenStorage TokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.post_deserialize', 'method' => 'onPostDeserialize'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Manipulate Entity
     * 
     * @param ObjectEvent $event
     * @return ObjectEvent
     */
    public function onPostDeserialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        /**
         * CompanyAware must be set:
         * @ParamConverter("variable", converter="fos_rest.request_body", "deserializationContext"={"CompanyAware"=true}}})
         */
        if(!$event->getContext()->attributes->containsKey('CompanyAware') ||
                !$event->getContext()->attributes->get('CompanyAware')->get()) {
            return $event;
        }

        //Check that a user is logged in
        if(!$this->tokenStorage->getToken() || !($user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())) {
            return $event;
        }

        if(!($user instanceof CompanyAwareInterface)) {
            return $event;
        }

        //Check that entity is not set with a company already
        /** @var CompanyAwareInterface $object */
        $object = $event->getObject();
        if(!($object instanceof CompanyAwareInterface) || $object->getCompany()) {
            return $event;
        }

        $object->setCompany($user->getCompany());

        return new ObjectEvent($event->getContext(), $object, $event->getType());
    }
}
```

#### CompanyAwareInterface:

```
namespace AppBundle\Request\API;

use AppBundle\Entity\Company;

interface CompanyAwareInterface {
    public function setCompany(Company $company);
    public function getCompany();
}
```

#### How to use

In order to use the `CompanyAware` listener, You need to add the following:

Make your `User` Entity to implement CompanyAwareInterface:

```
class User implements UserInterface, CompanyAwareInterface
```

Next, Do the same with every Entity you wish this listener to interact with:

```
class Resource implements CompanyAwareInterface
```

Last thing, add `CompanyAware` to your `@ParamConverter`:

```
@ParamConverter("resource", converter="fos_rest.request_body", options={"deserializationContext"={"CompanyAware"=false}})
```

*Yes, I can make the structure more abstract and easy to use. But it just doesn't worth it at the moment.*

Good luck!